# Is there a way of doing a "post switch" like operation with bool?

Tags: c++, boolean

I have a condition  like the following where I just want to have the second `bool` be the trigger for a single time, since this condition is invoked relatively often I don't like the idea of doing the assignment of it being false every time the condition is true so, I tried to take advantage of the order of logical AND and OR and the post increment operator. But it appears to work don't do what I expected it to do. So is there a way to make a post state switch for this line?

where `firstTitleNotSet` is:

```
bool firstTitleNotSet;
```

```
if (titleChangedSinceLastGet() || (p_firstTitleNotSet && p_firstTitleNotSet++))
```

The idea is that the first part is the primary trigger and the second is the trigger that only has to trigger the first time.

While I easily could do

```
if (titleChangedSinceLastGet() || p_firstTitleNotSet)
{
    firstTitleNotSet = false;
    //...
}
```

I don't like this as it is reassigning false when ever the conditional block is invoked.

So is there some way of "post change" the value of a bool from `true` to `false`? I know that this would work the other way around but this would negate the advantage of the method most time being the true trigger and therefor skipping the following check.

Note: The reasons for me making such considerations isntead of just taking the second case is, that this block will be called frequently so I'm looking to optimize its consumed runtime.

Comment: Have you tried something like `if( std::exchange( p_firstTitleNotSet, false ) == true )`?

Comment: @KABoissonneault: No, I have to admit I don't even know it. But I'm yet not quite sure anyway if this would really do the job, as it looks to me like a method that would be performed on every invokation leaving the value switching around, what is absolutely not what I'm requiring.

Comment: This seems like a useless micro-optimization, how likely is it that this single assignment every time the condition is true is going to make a noticeable difference in performance?

Comment: @Zaibis Trust me, if I understood your question properly, `std::exchange` is what you want. Pointlessly assigning `p_firstTitleNotSet` to false every iteration probably hurts your performance less than the extra branching caused by checking its current value before assignment (it might be a different story if it was atomic...). And on top of that, I think it's pretty expressive and readable.

Comment: @GuyGreer: might be. I never had hardware available to do such micro tests. But anyway and I might even accept it if it is that little of improvement compared to loss in readability that I decide against it. But that doesn't invalidate my question.

Comment: @KABoissonneault: Well the standard says that as soon a `||` branch evaluates true in it segements or false for `&&` it is ensured to mediately break the evaluation as the following expressions don't matter anymore. So the amount of checks I'm doing here is the same.

Comment: @Zaibis even if the number of "checks" is the same, using `||` and `&&` might be slower because of the branch, due to the possibility of misprediction. In some architectures a conditional instruction might be used instead of a jump

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: If you could widen that as part of an answer WHY this is the reason for my efforts might be wasted, I would welcome it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could do something like:

```
if (titleChangedSinceLastGet() ||
    (p_firstTitleNotSet ? ((p_firstTitleNotSet=false), true):false))
```

An alternative syntax would be:

```
if (titleChangedSinceLastGet() ||
    (p_firstTitleNotSet && ((p_firstTitleNotSet=false), true)))
```

Either one looks somewhat ugly. Note, however, that this is ***NOT*** the same as your other alternative:

```
if (titleChangedSinceLastGet() || p_firstTitleNotSet)
{
    p_firstTitleNotSet = false;
    //...
}
```

With your proposed alternative, pontificate the fact that `p_firstTitleNotSet` gets reset to `false` no matter what, even if the conditional was entered because `titleChangedSinceLastGet()`.

Comment: I'm aware of the last beeing not exactly the same as the other, but in my case it would both fit the required behavior. anyway, your second block is EAXACTLY what I tryed to achieve. I aggree with you that it is ugly. But is there some other way to achieve the same performance advantage from more readable code in this case?

Comment: If explicitly resetting the flag to `false` inside `if` works for you, use that. I'd be surprised if any difference in performance would actually be measurable. Modern, deep-pipelined CPUs are pretty good at what they do.

Comment: Could you explain the syntax or cite the concept involved in the `((p_firstTitleNotSet=false), )` segment? I've never seen that before.

Comment: @Zaibis what "performance advantage" are you talking about? Did you measure it and observed a difference?

Comment: @rtmh - `p_firstTitleNotSet=false` is an expression, like `a*b` or `foo()+3`. `=` is just an operator, like `*` or `+`. Except instead of multiplying or adding two values, it assigns the right-hand value to the left-hand value. The result of the expression is the same value. A comma is also an operator. The result of the `,` operator is the right-hand value.

Comment: Well the behavior is, I want to ensure that the first time it is called, the block is executed, no matter what happens, after that first time, I exclusively want to be depending on `titleChangedSinceLastGet()` But since the check is performed on both anyway I thought it would be an advantage to just swap the value of `p_firstTitleNotSet` a single time and not reasign it to `false` whenever the block is executed as I was expecting this to make me loose a bit of performance.

Comment: @rtmh: same as `,` is an operator here aswell. Making all previous evaluation beeing discarded and begin again. In this case just keeping the `true`

Comment: @tobi303: No I haven't but it is a fact that this will take fewer operations by standard definitions. You might be right to the point that this optimization might change so few that it isn't even any impact. But that it is optimization is given by the design of the language.

Answer (score 1):

A more readable way than the assignment inside a ternary operator inside an `or` inside an `if` would be just moving the operations to their own statements:

```
    bool needsUpdate = titleChangedSinceLastGet();
    if(!needsUpdate && firstTitleSet)
    {
        needsUpdate = true;
        firstTitleSet = false;
    }

    if(needsUpdate)
    {
        //...
    }
```

This is likely to produce very similar assembly than the less readable alternative proposed since ternary operators are mostly just syntactic sugar around if statements.

To demonstrate this I gave [GCC Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/) the following code:

extern bool first;
bool changed();

```
int f1()
{
  if (changed() ||
     (first ? ((first=false), true):false))
    return 1;
  return 0;
}

int f2()
{
  bool b = changed();
  if(!b && first)
  {
    b = true;
    first = false;
  }
  return b;
}
```

and the generated assembly had only small differences in the generated assembly after optimizations.  Certainly have a look for yourself.

I maintain, however, that this is highly unlikely to make a noticeable difference in performance and that this is more for interest's sake.
In my opinion:

```
    if(titleChangedSinceLastUpdate() || firstTitleSet)
    {
        firstTitleSet = false;
        //...
    }
```

is an (at least) equally good option.

You can compare the assembly of the above functions with this one to compare further.

```
bool f3()
{
  if(changed() || first)
  {
    first = false;
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: After the feedback I'm getting here and the adventage is really that small, I'll stay with the idea I had before which is your second example. but your first example with an aditional conditional will allways be worse, won't it?

Comment: @Zaibis I'll bet you a dollar that this produces very similar assembly to the "assignment inside a ternary inside an `or` inside an `if`" method.  From the compiler's point of the difference between a ternary operator and an `if` statement is just in how to parse it.

Comment: If you could elaboarte this in your answer you would get at minimum an upvote from me for that.

Answer (score 0):

That should work:

```
int firstTitleSet = 0;
if (titleChangedSinceLastGet() || (!firstTitleSet++))
```

If you wish to avoid overflow you can do:

```
int b = 1;
if (titleChangedSinceLastGet() || (b=b*2%4))
```

at the first iteration `b=2` while `b=0` at the rest of them.

Comment: This would let the programm crash all some hand full of minutes due to becomming correct in case of integer overflow (not mentioning integer overflow is undefined behavior), An Idea I came up with too, but the checks happen to often.

Comment: Again that is missing the point. It is true that this would behave as it is required. But this makes the performance even worse. I mean I'm trying to optimize away a single boolean asignment for each execution where as you'r example adds 2 integer operations + 1 integer asignment for each execution. This is missing the point of optimization. Also note "wishing to avoid overflow" should be given, as it is otherwise UB.

Comment: @Zaibis well, you should mention in your OP that you wish for **performance optimization**, It seems like you want only readable or nicely code.

Comment: @Zaibis Also, the UB is just **if** you overflow, like any `i++` on every program.

Comment: Obvisiously. Thats why I'm in every programm making sure a overflow won't happen. I allways use `i++` with a boundary (mostly anway because of a loop) that prevents `i` from overflowing. But here this meassures would destroy the idea of improvement I tryed to get.

Answer (score 0):

In this kind of situation, I usually write:

```
bool firstTitleNotSet = true;

if (titleChangedSinceLastGet() || firstTitleNotSet)
{
    if (firstTileNotSet) firstTitleNotSet = false;
    //...
}
```

That second comparison will likely be optimized by the compiler.

But if you have a preference for a post-increment operator:

```
int iterationCount = 0;
if (titleChangedSinceLastGet() || iterationCount++ != 0) 
{
    //...
}
```

Note that this will be a problem if `iterationCount` overflows, but the same is true of the `bool firstTitleNotSet` that you were post-incrementing.

In terms of code readability and maintainability, I would recommend the former.  If the logic of your code is sound, you can probably rely on the compiler to do a very good job optimizing it, even if it looks inelegant to you.

Comment: Well your first example is what I exactly want to avoid, if it isn't even worse what I'm doing since it has to conditions which get checked every time. And your second example would solve the problem If I hadn't to handle an integer overflow in that case.

Comment: I don't know if your motivation is code elegance or runtime performance, but it sounds like the latter.  It's likely that you're trying to optimize the source code in ways that probably will not benefit the runtime performance.  If you are concerned about this level of detail, I would recommend that you disassemble the code to see what the compiler is actually generating.  Even the disassembly doesn't tell you precisely what the performance will be in a deeply-pipelined modern processor, but you'll be much closer to ground truth.

Comment: Admited, I was unclear about that and clarifyed it in an edit. But also note that my first example, as Sam Varsh has now completed it in his answer is, in case the compiler implements the language correct an definetly not that elegant written code, but is by language definition never more operations then the other cases and depending on the runtime outcomes some times even fewer. So ofcourse the compiler oculd misinterpret it or it is on another level afected. But thats nothing I attempt to consider here.

Comment: I think you might find the disassembly very informative if you are inclined to look at it.

Comment: I made just a simple example what had not taken any effects from the whole big picture but doing `if (titleChangedSinceLastGet() || p_firstTitleNotSet)
{
    p_firstTitleNotSet = false;
    //...
}` contained an additional `movb $0, -5(%rbp)` which wasn't there in `if (titleChangedSinceLastGet() ||
    (p_firstTitleNotSet && ((p_firstTitleNotSet=false), true)))` I can't judge about the impact of it if any. but at least the binary output seems to be larger.

Comment: I applaud you for actually looking into this.